# Convert CURL POST command into Kotlin

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, curl

I need to use this CURL command in order to use the API of file.io

```
curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://file.io
```

This needs to be send over POST.

How do i convert this into usable Kotlin code?

I tried a lot of stuff and I even tried DavidWebb, which is a library for sending rest requests, even that didn't work(Getting 400).

Any ideas?

Comment: curl -F actually using multipart/form-data to upload a file.

So basically you can look for multipart file uploading in kotlin to achieve the same.